# Lattice formula syntax for 'calibration' function in caret

Tags: r, caret, calibration

I would like to use the function 'calibration' from the caret package to produce calibration plots for a few classifiers that I have. Unfortunately I am having trouble understanding the documentation given by ?calibration:

> **calibration(x, data = NULL, 
>               class = NULL, etc...)**
>
> Arguments
>
> x  a lattice formula (see xyplot for syntax) where the *left-hand side
>   of the formula is a factor class variable of the observed outcome and
>   the right-hand side specifies one or model columns corresponding to a
>   numeric ranking variable for a model* (e.g. class probabilities). The
>   classification variable should have two levels.

The inputs I was expecting to have to give were a vector of predictions for my classifier, together with the vector of corresponding true values, in order to plot something like the first of the two graphs in [this image](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/plot_compare_calibration_001.png). Am I just confused as to what kind of plot calibration() produces? If not then how do I turn my vector of predictions and vector of true values into the required 'lattice formula'?

To clarify: I can see from the italicised text that the lattice formula does seem to represent the same information as my two vectors, I'm just unclear as to how to put them in the required format, and looking at ?xyplot has only confused me further.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the `examples` section in the same help file?

The example there has the syntax:

```
calibration(obs ~ lda + qda, data = testProbs)
```

where `lda` and `qda` are columns in a data frame with the class probabilities and `obs` is the factor column with the class labels.